# When I publish my VS2017 project it cant be install at customer site

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My program runs and build just fine in VS2017, but when I publish my project it cant be installed at customer site.

When running the `setup.exe` dialog box shows and appear saying..

Cant call method 'End validation' all elements have not been validated.. , cant find any information out there.. do you know whats wrong ?

```
[2019-03-06 18:27:31] System.InvalidOperationException
        - Det går inte att anropa metoden 'EndValidation' om inte alla element har verifierats. Anrop av 'ValidateEndElement' som motsvarar anrop av 'ValidateElement' kan saknas.
        - Källa: System.Xml
        - Stackspårning:
            vid System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.EndValidation()
            vid System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Slut på stackspårningen från föregående plats där ett undantag utlöstes ---
            vid System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            vid System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Comment: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237855/how-do-you-add-supportedos-to-a-windows-click-once-application-manifest), the English version of the error message is: "The 'EndValidation' method cannot not be called when all the elements have not been validated. 'ValidateEndElement' calls corresponding to 'ValidateElement' calls might be missing."  Perhaps that post may help you.

Comment: Problem solved.. I deleted application.manifest file from the projekt and problem was solved.. I have no clue where that file came from...